# Cron job from cpanel retunning error while running script from URL is not reurning any error

Tags: php, web-services, cpanel

I wrote a script on my web server. when I run my code using the URL (http://www.eurekabd.com/RMS/corn.php) and found ok. Then I made a corn job scheduler in cPanel by this command /usr/local/bin/php /home/eurekabd/public_html/RMS/corn.php. When cron job run this command it sends me mail that

Warning: file_get_contents(shakil.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/eurekabd/public_html/RMS/corn.php on line 12

[image: when Run from URL]

[image]

[image]

```
  <?php

$response = get_web_page("http://144.48.2.11/Test_PHP/live_check.php");
//$response = get_web_page("http://localhost/phpScriptTesting/request.php");
$txtFile = "shakil.txt";
echo $response;
/*if(! filesize( $txtFile ) )
{
    echo " Not EMPTY FILE ";
}*/
echo "Server is =".$response;
if ((trim(file_get_contents('shakil.txt')) != false) && ($response == "OK")) {
    echo "-->I have some data to send.";
    //http://144.48.2.11/Test_PHP/index_2.php/?data={1239{fnc:15,sts:[0,8,25,526,19][0103044396424b7f0c][01030caf854366a45b436695684366376d][01030c9ba63b447bb33b7249523a1d4641][01030c00003f8000003f8000003f80d6f8][010304999a3f1924ba][x][x][x][x][x][0b03080113045403ff03f057ea][x]}})

    $file_content = file_get_contents("shakil.txt");
    $file_content_separated_by_spaces = explode(";", $file_content);
    //print_r ($file_content_separated_by_spaces)."</br>";
    $loop_size = sizeof($file_content_separated_by_spaces)-2;
    echo $loop_size;
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $loop_size; $x++) {
        $dataFormatforServer = str_replace(' ', '_', $file_content_separated_by_spaces[$x]);
        $textData = "http://144.48.2.11/Test_PHP/index_3.php/?data=".$dataFormatforServer;
        //$textData = "http://localhost/phpScriptTesting/test.php/?data=".$dataFormatforServer;
        echo $textData."</br>";
        $sendData = get_web_page($textData);
        //echo $sendData."</br>";
    }

    $file_to_delete = 'shakil.txt';
    unlink($file_to_delete);
    $my_file = 'shakil.txt';
    $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
}

else{   
    echo "I don't Have Any Data to send.";
}

function get_web_page($url) {
    $options = array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,   // return web page
                CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,  // don't return headers
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,   // follow redirects
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,     // stop after 10 redirects
                CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",     // handle compressed
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "test", // name of client
                CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,   // set referrer on redirect
                CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 300,    // time-out on connect
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 300,    // time-out on response
            ); 

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $response = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    $content  = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $content;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may add/change php.ini attributes for that..

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

It may resolve the issue..